# how to get only the number for how many certain keys (starts with) there are in a twig

Tags: twig

I'm struggling to find a way to count certain keys in an array so I don't need to type all the keys in a computed_twig element for some calculations.
I'm trying to get how many keys (questions) in the form so I can use the number in another step.

Questions are keys and each starts with `q_`. In this example there are 5 questions (q_1 to q_5). Here is a sample of my form (actual form has many groups of such questions with tens of questions, all starting with `q_` then a sequential number e.g. `q_1` ,... `q_32` etc). I'm trialing in [this twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/ub9mhg/7)

This is a minimal sample of my webform yaml:

```
qp1:
  '#type': wizard_page
  '#title': 'Part I'
  '#open': true
  ps1:
    '#type': details
    '#title': title...
    '#required': true
    '#attributes':
      class:
        - qp1_1
    q_1:
      '#type': radios
      '#title': q1.....
      '#options':
        - 'option 1 with value 0'
        - 'option 2 with value 1'
        - 'option 3 with value 2'
        - 'option 4 with value 3'
      '#required': true
    q_2:
      '#type': radios
      '#title': q2....
      '#options':
        - 'option 1 with value 0'
        - 'option 2 with value 1'
        - 'option 3 with value 2'
        - 'option 4 with value 3'
      '#required': true
    q_3:
      '#type': radios
      '#title': q3.....
      '#options':
        - 'option 1 with value 0'
        - 'option 2 with value 1'
        - 'option 3 with value 2'
        - 'option 4 with value 3'
      '#required': true
    q_4:
      '#type': radios
      '#title': q4.......
      '#options':
        - 'option 1 with value 0'
        - 'option 2 with value 1'
        - 'option 3 with value 2'
        - 'option 4 with value 3'
      '#required': true
    q_5:
      '#type': radios
      '#title': q5........
      '#options':
        - 'option 1 with value 0'
        - 'option 2 with value 1'
        - 'option 3 with value 2'
        - 'option 4 with value 3'
      '#required': true
```

First, I tried this but it returns all the correct keys while I only want the number of how many they are (i.e. `5` in this example):

```
{% for qs in qp1.ps1|keys %}
    {% if qs starts with 'q_' %}
    {{ qs }} {# this returns q_1 q_2 q_3 q_4 q_5 #}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Second, this is giving me as many "3"s as there correctly are `q_` keys as `33333` but this is not what I want and I don't understand where the `3` came from!

```
{% for qs in qp1.ps1|keys %}
    {% if qs starts with 'q_' %}
    {{ qs | length }} {# this returns 3 3 3 3 3 (number "3" 5 times !) #}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: To answer your questions where the `3` comes from, you are looping all the keys inside `ps1`. The keys are `#type`, `#title`, ...`q_1`, `q_2`, etc. Basically your code is printing the length of the key (`strlen`) of each key starting with `q_` and `strlen('q_1') == 3`

Comment: @DarkBee re the number 3, isn't the key length 4 in this example ?! (#type, #title, #options, and #required)

Comment: Have a look at the reworked [fiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/ub9mhg/9), you aren't printing the `length` of an array, but of a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more clean solution would be to use the filter [`filter`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/filter.html):

```
{{ qp1.ps1|filter((v,k) => k starts with 'q_')|length }}
```

You can assign the filtered result to a variable if needed be as well, e.g.

```
{% set questions = qp1.ps1|filter((v,k) => k starts with 'q_') %}
{{ questions | length }}
```

[demo](https://fiddle.nette.org/twig/#8867b0b5cd)

Comment: thanks. I'd tried the reduce filter but still struggling with it. I tried {{ questions | reduce((carry, v) => carry + v) }} but this isn't working

Comment: Consider creating a new question for this problem

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out a short clean answer for my case but I'm still interested to know any other solution without the need to use the number of non-relevant keys. The below twig worked nicely. the number "4" is the number of the non `q_` keys under the element `ps1` .
`((qp1.ps1)|length)` returns the number of all the keys (9 in this example here). The keys I want to count are only the ones that start with `q_` and they are 5 keys in this example form. So I just deducted the number of **non** `q_` keys (`#type`, `#title`, `#required`, `#attributes`) as follows:

```
{{ ((qp1.ps1)|length) - 4 }}
```

I still prefer a way without having to use the number of non-relevant keys esp. if using the "starts with" filter for the sake of learning and also to avoid having to update the twig every time the number of non-relevant keys may change.